# How can I use the geopy library to obtain a list or a consultation of all the cities of a country

Tags: python-3.x, geopy

I want to get a list of cities in Colombia to enter them into a database and I found the `geopy` library to do this, I don't know how to do it so I need help I have the following code but it tells me that it does not support the Key error: address

```
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

# Crear un objeto geocoder
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my-app")

# Especificar la dirección de un punto en el país
direccion = "Calle 1, Ciudad, Colombia"

# Realizar la geocodificación para obtener la ubicación
ubicacion = geolocator.geocode(direccion)

# Obtener las ciudades del país a partir de la ubicación
ciudades = [ciudad.split(",")[-1].strip() for ciudad in ubicacion.raw['address']['locality']]

# Imprimir las ciudades encontradas
for ciudad in ciudades:
    print(ciudad)
```